# how i can encode my data using library requests

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

im scrappy some data from a web site, but the data is in unicode and i want transform to utf-8

```
    url = 'https://www.cartolafcbrasil.com.br/scouts/cartola-fc- 
    2018/rodada-1'
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    variaveis = []
    table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))
    print(df)
```

[                           0      1       2  3       4            5   \
0                        Nome  Clube  PreÃ§o  J  MÃ©dia  Ãlt. Pont.
1              Serginho (MEI)    NaN    1578  1    1790         1790
2                 Otero (MEI)    NaN    1481  1    1650         1650
3           Rodriguinho (MEI)    NaN    2308  1    1650         1650
4               Richard (MEI)    NaN    1461  1    1620         1620
5             Carlinhos (LAT)    NaN    1440  1    1590         1590
6        Gustavo Blanco (MEI)    NaN    1268  1    1540         1540
7                  Jory (GOL)    NaN    1013  1    1370         1370
8        Thiago Carleto (LAT)    NaN    1254  1    1320         1320
9        VÃ­ctor Cuesta (ZAG)    NaN    1385  1    1310         1310
10         Yago Pikachu (LAT)    NaN    1433  1    1280         1280
11               Wagner (MEI)    NaN    1350  1    1260         1260
12       Lucas PaquetÃ¡ (MEI)    NaN    1798  1    1210         1210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass encoding paramater to pandas [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.read_html.html#pandas-read-html):

```
df = pd.read_html(str(table), encoding="UTF-8")
```